# how Set values to my object in extjs

Tags: extjs

Hello my code is  the following

```
  `var form = me.down('evaluationform').getForm();
   var evaluation = form.getFieldValues();`
```

And my aim is to set some other value(ID) to my evaluation for example this
  `me.record.get('id')`

I try many things but..  like this valuation.setValue(me.record.get('id'));please tell me how can i do this

Comment: "me.record.get('id')" on New field or in a Existent field ?

Comment: Dear Tato, if you want to hide your question from the world simply delete it, don't change its body to gibberish. That's kind of rude and makes the people taking their time to answer or edit look silly.

Comment: yes i now it is not good maner , but i can't delete question, becouse it has unswer , i whand delete my account , i sent message about deleting my account but..

Answer (score -1):

**New Field:**

```
var newValue= {"name": me.record.get('id')};
Ext.Object.merge(evaluation ,newValue);
```

**Existent Field:**

Use sencha function: [setValue](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-method-setValue)

- Find the field of your component, and set the value.